# Pass informations between two ColumnDefinition?

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid, observable

I have a problem to understand how can i show details of a selected cells into a second ColumnDefinition. The Details-Propertys are into a Observable Dictionary with KeyValuePair setup.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons.Values}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="0">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Key.Name" Header="K1 Regler"  Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Background="Azure">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label Foreground="Black" Content="{Binding Path=Key.Name}" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

How can i pass the Data between the ColumnDefinitions if i selected one of the Datagrid cells?

Comment: Would do you mean by "selected column"?
Usually you select cells a/o rows...

Comment: Usually you would do the commumciation through the viewmodel. And let both columns (or better: their cells) bind to the same data a/o also set that data. For example some "SelectedItem" property...

Comment: How can i realise it?
My Idea is to select a cell on the first             ColumnDefinition of a Datagrid with the ItemSource Persons.Values and show on the second ColumnDefinition with a TextBox the Value.Name attribute.

Comment: Normally in a DataGrid all cells of the same row share the same data object, so for example you can show "FamilienName" in the first column and "VorName" in the second , or such like, you just have to bind to those two properties, but nothing special/complicated.

Comment: Do you have TWO datagrids? And you want the data selected in the first grid to be also displayed in the second GRID (in more detail?)

Comment: Yes @lidqy that is the idea behind my work. i have to Grids in two different  ColumnDefinition. And i want you display data into the second Datagrid if i selected a cell of the first Grid.

Comment: Then you need to add a property like SelectedPerson to your main viewmodel (the one that also has that "Persons" dictionary)
In the first datagrid you need to bind grid.SelectedItem to vm.SelectedPerson, in the second grid you would bind one way to vm.SelectedPerson.
But actually I wouldn't use a datagrid for the details, but rather a propertygrid or something similar....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding to the `DataGrid` element's `SelectedItem`?

Check the `TextBlock` below, you can replace it with `DataGrid` and bind to `ItemsSource` if that's what you are looking for.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="PersonsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons.Values}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Key.Name" Header="K1 Regler"  Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Azure">
                            <Grid>
                                <Label Foreground="Black" Content="{Binding Path=Key.Name}" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=PersonsGrid, Path=SelectedItem}" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```